# How to test mqtt on docker in windows?

Tags: windows, docker, mqtt, mosquitto

I have pulled the eclipse-mosquitto image on the docker. How can I test the mqtt client by subscribing and publishing some message through docker?

Following are the details of my system:

Operating System: Windows 10 Home

Docker version 19.03.1

Can someone please guide me with the steps on how to test the mqtt on docker in windows 10?

Thank you

Comment: Without knowing how you've started the container (how you've mapped the ports) we can't really answer this. Also we have no idea what MQTT clients you've got installed on your host system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test using MQTT client docker container.

- **server**

Start `eclipse-mosquitto` container

```
docker run --name mq -it -p 1883:1883 -p 9001:9001  eclipse-mosquitto
```

- **client:**

Then open another terminal window and run subscriber command using docker MQTT client

```
docker run --rm -it   --link mq   ruimarinho/mosquitto mosquitto_sub -h mq -t '#'
```

Now open another terminal window and publish a message, you will able to see message in window 2.

```
docker run --rm -it   --link mq   ruimarinho/mosquitto mosquitto_pub -h mq -t home-assistant/switch/1/on -m "Docker pub-subtest message"
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for the solution. It works perfectly!

Comment: Glad it help you

Comment: I got this:
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm/v7) and no specific platform was requested
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error

Answer (score 0):

You need to install an MQTT client that can do both Publish and Subscribe.  I tend to use the Node.JS MQTT module that includes a client that will do both.

You will need to install Node.JS first. Then do a:

```
> npm install mqtt
```

This will install the MQTT Node.JS module under the ./node_modules directory in your current directory.

After this, you need to run a Subscriber and a Publisher.  The Subscriber you run like so:

```
> node ./node_modules/mqtt/mqtt.js sub -t "my/local/#" -h "mqtt-broker-host.home.local" -vv
```

Where `mqtt-broker-host.home.local` is either the FQDN or the IP address of your MQTT Broker container.

In another terminal session, you can run MQTT publishers:

```
> node ./node_modules/mqtt/mqtt.js pub -t "my/local/test-topic" -h "mqtt-broker-host.home.local' -m '{"msg": "This is a test" }'
```

In your 'sub' terminal you should now see the "This is a test" message if everything is working correctly.  If not, look in the 'pub' terminal session for any error messages.  If there is none, then you should look at your MQTT Broker log file to see what it thinks is going one.

Answer (score 0):

Great thanks to Adiii, I am also new to docker, just add something for my own try;I tried his code

> docker run --rm -it   --link mq   ruimarinho/mosquitto mosquitto_sub -h mq -t '#'

and I got

> Error: Connection refused

Then I found it was mosquitto.conf setting has not allowed anonymous connection, I navigate to the .conf and deleted content and add these:

```
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data
user mosquitto
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log
log_dest stdout
```

It is also necessary to have "--link mq" to link both containers

**Very importantly, restart the container after the change**

Then I tried again to use

```
mosquito_sub -h mq -t '#"
```

it successfully made the sub and pub test as Adiii posted works.

It took me several days to troubleshoot, thanks

some inspiration comes from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juSoczXtlxA

Comment: make sure that you specified the right docker container name after the --link instaead of mq